# searching in file depending on two criteria

Tags: excel, vba

this macro will open the last saved file which beginns with ECL.
and will be searched in the ECL file for the defined value in thisworkbook in worksheet: "Main" cell: B3
but I am trying to make this macro to search deppending on two criteria For example in B3 and B4 ( I Mean when two conditions fit) but I did not find the way yet.
thank you in advance

```
Sub Findandkopy()
Dim cellscontents As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim loDeinWert As String
Dim sfirstaddress As String
Dim ESLWb As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Const strPath As String = "L:\10 \05\HGB\"
  Dim strFile As String, strFile2Open As String, dteFile As Date, dteLast As Date


 strFile = Dir$(strPath & "ECL*.xlsm")
  If strFile <> "" Then
    Do
      dteFile = FileDateTime(strPath & strFile)
      If dteFile > dteLast Then
        strFile2Open = strFile
        dteLast = dteFile
      End If
      strFile = Dir$
    Loop Until strFile = ""
    Workbooks.Open strPath & strFile2Open
  Else
    MsgBox "NO FILES FOUNDED!"
  End If

loDeinWert = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("B3").Value 

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like "ECL*" Then
        Set ESLWb = wb
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb

If ESLWb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "ECL* not found"
    Exit Sub
Else
ESLWb.Worksheets("All").Activate
End If
Set rng = ESLWb.Worksheets("All").Range("B:B").Find(loDeinWert)
If rng Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Wert " & loDeinWert & " not found!"
Else
  sfirstaddress = rng.Address
  Do
    rng.EntireRow.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp) _
      .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Set rng = ESLWb.Worksheets("Alle").Range("B:B").FindNext(rng)
  Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Address <> sfirstaddress
End If
ESLWb.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: But what criteria must B4 meat? Is it somehow based on the `loDeinWert` string? Is it  defined exactly in the same way? Let us say: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("B4").Value`?

Comment: You could just filter the **All** sheet based on the values in `B3` and `B4`. Then get the filtered rows. If you get rows back, use those to run your code